# How to connect my prestashop with odoo 9

Tags: prestashop, odoo

I have a prestashop website. I am new to Odoo 9. I dont know how to connect the prestashop with Odoo 9. Can anyone please tell me how to connect it. I need step by step procedure. I am awaiting for the reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a [module](http://addons.prestashop.com/fr/outils-administration-modules-prestashop/8056-openerp-connecteur.html) for that , otherwise you should develop it, the module should include order, customer, products, stock, categories synchronization.
To create it, you should read about prestashop action hooks (when a client pass an order, a client creates an account, ...) you can read [this](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks) or [forum post](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/276894-how-to-use-action-hooks/).
To have synchronization work from odoo to prestashop you should use cron jobs to import data(products, clients, orders, categories) daily 
to prestashop.